# What is the order of namespaces in inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, namespaces, name-mangling

A derived class has access to its base class member functions implicitly, unless I am mistaken. A derived class can also access its base class' attributes by prefixing a call to them like this: BaseClass.base_attribute. But I seemingly do not understand how instances of a derived class can use the methods of the base class. Example:

```
class Visitor():
    """ Interface to Visitor
    
    provide an interface to visitors that
    perform an operation on a data collection """
    
    def visitProduce():
        pass
    def visitMeat():
        pass
    def visitBakedGoods():
        pass
    def visitDairy():
        pass
    def visitNonFood():
        pass
        
        
        
class PriceVisitor(Visitor):
    __cost = 0.0        # total cost of groceries
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cost = 0.0
    def visitProduce(self, p):
        self.__cost += p.price()
    def visitMeat(self, m):
        self.__cost += m.price()
    def visitBakedGoods(self, b):
        self.__cost += b.price()
    def visitDairy(self, d):
        self.__cost += d.price()
    def visitNonFood(self, nf):
        self.__cost += nf.price()
        
        
class Groceries():
    shopping_cart = []      # list of grocery items
    
    def Groceries(self):
        self.shopping_cart = []     
    def addProduce(self, p):
        pass
    def addMeat(self, m, lb):
        pass
    def addBakedGoods(self, b):
        pass
    def addDairy(self, d):
        pass
    def addNonFood(self, nf):
        pass
    def accept(self, v):
        pass
    def getShoppingCart(self):
        print(self.shopping_cart)
    def calculateCost(self, v):
        for item in self.shopping_cart:
            item.accept(v)
            item.details()
            print('Total cost is: $', v.__cost)
            
            
            
class Produce(Groceries):
    def addProduce(self):
        Groceries.shopping_cart.append(self)
            
    def accept(self, v):
        v.visitProduce(self)
        
    def price(self):
        return self.__price
        
    def details(self):
        print(self.__name, ' for: $', self.__price + '')
        
        
        
class Apples(Produce):
    __name = None
    __price = 3.25
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

And here is a test of the Apple, Produce, Groceries, and PriceVisitor classes

```
import VisitorPattern as vp

def main():
    # Visitor object
    my_visitor = vp.PriceVisitor()
    
    # Grocery object stores objects in its shopping_cart attribute
    my_groceries = vp.Groceries()
    
    # Add items
    red_apple = vp.Apples('red apple')
    gold_apple = vp.Apples('gold apple')
    red_apple.addProduce()
    gold_apple.addProduce()
    
    my_groceries.getShoppingCart()
    
    my_groceries.calculateCost(my_visitor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, the way I understand it is that upon the construction of the instance of Apple, it has access to Produce's method price(). Calling this method with an instance of the Apple class will then pass its own instance in place of the 'self'. The program then returns the value of the __price attribute belonging to the instance calling the method, in this case Apple. However, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\josep_000\Documents\School\Summer 2015\Python Assignment 4>python test.
py
[<VisitorPattern.Apples object at 0x026E0830>, <VisitorPattern.Apples object at
0x026E0910>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 20, in main
    my_groceries.calculateCost(my_visitor)
  File "C:\Users\josep_000\Documents\School\Summer 2015\Python Assignment 4\Visi
torPattern.py", line 60, in calculateCost
    item.accept(v)
  File "C:\Users\josep_000\Documents\School\Summer 2015\Python Assignment 4\Visi
torPattern.py", line 71, in accept
    v.visitProduce(self)
  File "C:\Users\josep_000\Documents\School\Summer 2015\Python Assignment 4\Visi
torPattern.py", line 28, in visitProduce
    self.__cost += p.price()
  File "C:\Users\josep_000\Documents\School\Summer 2015\Python Assignment 4\Visi
torPattern.py", line 74, in price
    return self.__price
AttributeError: 'Apples' object has no attribute '_Produce__price'
```

How does the binding and namespaces actually work in inheritance? I could just write the price() method in each of Produce's derived classes, but that would defeat the point of inheritance. I think my problem also stems from name mangling, but still don't know what happens if I don't make my attributes 'private'. Clarification would be great. Thanks

## Edit

I declared the constructor of Groceries wrong:

```
# Wrong way
def Groceries(self):   
    self.shopping_cart = []

# Should be
def __init__(self):
    self.__shopping_cart = []
```

The product of a full time job and homework in the evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the order of namespaces in inheritance?

Python uses the Method Resolution Order to find the method bound to that instance of the object.

It also invokes name mangling, which is why you can't find the method, `_Produce__price`. You're trying to use `.__price` but when it is inherited, Python adds the name of the class to the front of the name. Don't use two underscores, change the two underscores to one, and your code will work as you expect, and you'll consistently look up `._price` which won't invoke the name mangling.

See the docs for more on this:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to all your questions but I hope the following code sheds some light on how to do inheritance in Python.

```
class Produce(object):

    def __init__(self, name=None, price=None):
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name

    @property
    def bulk_price(self):
        return self.__price * 100

class Apple(Produce):

    def __init__(self, name="Apple"):
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = 3.25
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(self.__name, self.__price)

a = Apple("Gold Apple")
print a
print a.bulk_price
# Gold Apple
# 325.0
```

As you can see, I made `name` and `price` inaccessible in both classes. This way, I cannot just call them explicitly, i.e. `a.__price`. By using `super` as well in the child class, I am able to avoid referring to the base class further *while still having access to its methods*.

Comment: I must still be programming with C++ in mind: is it good practice to have class attributes, or is it better to leave it to the instance to create its own attribute?

Comment: I wouldn't call it good practice, but I see no reason *to not* have it in some instances. Admittedly, I have barely used class attributes and methods in my experience with Python so I don't think I'm qualified to answer that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have saw your error, your parent need to call child's function, but you have not transferred child to parent, so it will get the errors.Now I give my example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, handler):
        self.a = 5
        self.real_handler = handler

    def get(self):
        print "value a = %d"%self.a
        self.real_handler.put()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self, self)    ##transport B to A
        self.b = 3

    def get(self):
        print "value b is %d"%self.b
        A.get(self)

    def put(self):
        self.b = 6
        print "value b change into %d"%self.b

if __name__=="__main__":
    b = B()
    b.get()
```

In parent B, it will call the child A's fuction `put()`.  I hope this can help you.